# sox cannot play files with a-law encoding

Tags: encoding, sox

I am in linux mint 14 and trying to play a .sph file using sox with `play foo.sph`
and got the following error:
`play FAIL formats: can't open input file 'foo.sph': sph: unsupported coding 'alaw'`

Doesn't sox support alaw encoding? What can I do to play this file? Note that it can successfully play ulaw. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the relevant SoX source code (from `src/sphere.c`, starting at line 74):

```
if (!strcasecmp(fldsval, "ulaw") || !strcasecmp(fldsval, "mu-law"))
  encoding = SOX_ENCODING_ULAW;
else if (!strcasecmp(fldsval, "pcm"))
  encoding = SOX_ENCODING_SIGN2;
else {
  lsx_fail_errno(ft, SOX_EFMT, "sph: unsupported coding `%s'", fldsval);
  /* ... */
}
```

As you can see, the format handler only knows about µ-law and PCM encodings, nothing else. As you say, SoX does have decoding routines for A-law; therefore, it would suffice to add these lines:

```
else if (!strcasecmp(fldsval, "alaw"))
  encoding = SOX_ENCODING_ALAW;
```

Obviously, this is only going to help you if you can compile SoX yourself from source with this addition.

---

A probably simpler way is to use the libsndfile driver, which is supposed to support A-law encoding in Sphere files: `play -t sndfile foo.sph`